# networkx for calculating closeness centrality

Tags: networkx

I am trying to understand if there is a closeness centrality function similar to R's igraph in python's package networkx. I am looking to calculate both the in-closeness centrality and the out-closeness centrality, but I dont think thats possible in networkx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `nx.closeness_centrality`:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph([(0,1), (0,2), (0,3), (2,1), (3,2)])
Out = nx.closeness_centrality(G, reverse=True)
In = nx.closeness_centrality(G)
```

Output

```
Out
{0: 1.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.3333333333333333, 3: 0.4444444444444444}
In
{0: 0.0, 1: 0.75, 2: 0.6666666666666666, 3: 0.3333333333333333}
```

Comment: you are the best! thanks so much!!! i have been trying to figure this out for hours? how did you know this since the documentation doesn't mention reverse parameter

Comment: @qfd I guess is a parameter recently added to the function. [Here](http://dschult-networkx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.centrality.closeness_centrality.html#networkx.algorithms.centrality.closeness_centrality) you can find it. Glad to be of help.